# Elementary graph theory question, frequency as a result of degrees of separation

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph of nodes, all nodes are connected to *n* other nodes. Periodically a random node emits a pulse. What is the frequency with which you receive pulses from *k* steps away, compared to at one degree of separation from pulse emitter (k = 1)?

The connections are one-way, and the pulse propagates node to node, away from the pulse emitter. The pulse never loops.

Comment: Which other nodes does a node receive the pulses from, and how?

Comment: the nodes it has connections to. connections are one-way, propagation away from pulse emitter.

Comment: So a node that receives a pulse also sends it on to other nodes that haven't received it?

Comment: ah, propagates it

Comment: Do the $n$ connections count both incoming and outgoing connections, so some nodes may have no incoming connections or no outgoing connections at all, for example?

Comment: no, only outgoing, one-way.

Comment: also, no loops.

Comment: I added some context, and what I assume to find

Answer (score 0):

The pulse has reached (¹+²+³+⁴+…….^k) nodes at distance *k* away from pulse emitter. That means a pulse reaches 1/n * (¹+²+³+⁴+…….^k) times more nodes when at distance *k* compared to one degree of separation from pulse emitter (k = 1). The frequency can then be calculated relative k = 1 as 1/n * (¹+²+³+⁴+…….^k), k = 1 giving  the lowest frequency of 1/n * n¹ = 1.